# Setting current activity as startup activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

My app switches between different activities, with each activity being killed after switching to another one. This works totally fine, but what I am trying to do is, when the user kills the app (either by pressing the Back key or in some other way), that its last running activity is be the next time the app is launched.

I tried ...

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
```

... but this does not seem to work across other activities.

Is there another way of doing this? I also thought about directly editing the manifest, but concluded that it would probably not work and would be very dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, for example, you have 3 activities: `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`. If the user exits the app via `ActivityB`, and later starts the app up again, you want `ActivityB` to start first.

You can do this on two ways.

**First**, you can have a single `Activity` with a placeholder for one of 3 [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in it. Then you can substitute the fragment as needed.

**Second**, you can store the last opened activity in preferences, using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html). You can do this in the `onStart()` of each `ActivityX` you have, and read it off when you determine which activity to start.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// save:
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
edit.commit();

// restore later:
String activityName = prefs.getString("lastActivity", YourActivityA.getClass().getName());
```

//    if (activityName == null) activityName = YourActivityA.getClass().getName();
    /// start that activity as needed

Comment: Thanks!
This was exactly what I needed, however, there is a little mistake in there:
The method PreferenceManager.getString() requires 2 parameters, the last one is the default value, making your last line unnecessary. However thanks, I did not know there was such thing as a PreferenceManager...